# How to sort react-bootstrap Table component

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm new to React and am using the Table component from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

I want to sort my table in ascending order of the 'Days Till Expiry' column.
[image: My React App]

But the Table component doesn't have a sorting property, does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [react-bootstrap-table](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table) then use these [examples](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#sort)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I did it by adding an onClick event on the header and having said event trigger a sorting function I'd programmed.  To ensure the change shows up, I added a state I could just update to render the table whenever I made a change.  Here is what it looks like:

```
    <th className ="text-center" onClick= {()=>sortFunction('headerName')}>HeaderName</th>
```

and here is an abridged version of the function itself:

```
    function sortFunction(col){
    switch (col){
    case "headerName":
    dataArray.sort((a, b)=>{
      if(a.attribute>b.attribute){
        return 1:-1;
      }
      if(a.attribute<b.attribute){
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    break;
    default:
    //you might want to do something as default, I don't
    break;
    setSort(sort+1);
```

just keep in mind I declared the state with:

```
    const [sort, setSort] = useState(0);
```

When comparing two strings, make sure to use localeCompare and not ><.  The beauty of using a custom sorting function is you get to choose how things are compared, meaning you can sort however you would like.  I also added another variable later to handle the order and swapping the order when sorting the table.

In your case I would do something like:

```
    dataArray.sort((a, b)=>{
      if(new Date(a.daysTillExpiry).getTime()>new Date(b.daysTillExpiry).getTime()){
        return 1;
      }
      if(new Date(a.daysTillExpiry).getTime()<new Date(b.daysTillExpiry).getTime()){
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setSort(sort+1);
```

Keep in mind I didn't try it specifically for your order so maybe you'll have to reverse the return 1 and return -1 to get the proper ordering.